# Rock Paper Scissors: How can I disable buttons to end game?

Tags: javascript

I want to disable the buttons after the user or computer reaches 5 points. I've been trying to remove the event listeners for the rock, paper and scissor divs where it says "if userScore===5" and "compScore===5" in the win/lose functions but it doesn't work. I've seen people disable the buttons to end the game, but my 'buttons' are images in divs that I added a click event listener to so I don't think that would work in my case.

```
let userScore = 0;
let compScore = 0;

const userScore_span = document.getElementById("user-score");
const compScore_span = document.getElementById("comp-score");
const scoreBoard_div = document.querySelector(".score-board");
const result_p = document.querySelector(".result > p");
const rock_div = document.getElementById("r");
const paper_div = document.getElementById("p");
const scissors_div = document.getElementById("s");

//Gets random selection from computer 
function getComputerSelection() {
    const choices=['r','p','s'];
    const result = Math.floor(Math.random()*3);
    return choices[result]
} 
//Converts r,p,s to rock, paper, scissors for output on screen
function convertToWord(letter) {
    if (letter === 'r') return "Rock";
    if (letter === 'p') return "Paper";
    return "Scissors";
}

function win(playerSelection, computerSelection) {
    userScore++;
    userScore_span.innerHTML = userScore;
    compScore_span.innerHTML = compScore;

    if (userScore < 5){result_p.innerHTML = `${convertToWord(playerSelection)} beats ${convertToWord(computerSelection)}. You win! =D`;
    }else if(userScore===5){result_p.innerHTML='Game over, you win! Refresh to play again';
 rock_div.removeEventListener('click', () => game("r"));
 
 paper_div.removeEventListener('click', () => game("p"));
 
 scissors_div.removeEventListener('click', () => game("s"));
    
  } 
}


function lose(playerSelection, computerSelection) {
    compScore++;
    userScore_span.innerHTML = userScore;
    compScore_span.innerHTML = compScore;
    
    if (compScore<5){result_p.innerHTML = `${convertToWord(computerSelection)} beats ${convertToWord(playerSelection)}. You lose =(`;
    }else if(compScore===5){result_p.innerHTML='Game over, you lose! Refresh to play again';
 rock_div.removeEventListener('click', () => game("r"));
 
 paper_div.removeEventListener('click', () => game("p"));
 
 scissors_div.removeEventListener('click', () => game("s"));
    
  }
}

function draw() {
    userScore_span.innerHTML = userScore;
    compScore_span.innerHTML = compScore;
    result_p.innerHTML = `It\'s a tie!`;
}

function game(playerSelection) {
    const computerSelection = getComputerSelection();
    
    if (playerSelection === computerSelection) {
        draw(playerSelection, computerSelection);
      } else if (playerSelection === 'r' && computerSelection === 's'){
        win(playerSelection, computerSelection);  
      }else if (playerSelection === 'p' && computerSelection === 'r'){
        win(playerSelection, computerSelection);
      }else if (playerSelection === 's' && computerSelection === 'p'){
        win(playerSelection, computerSelection);
      }else{
        lose(playerSelection, computerSelection);
      }      
    }  

  //Links images to game play  
 rock_div.addEventListener('click', () => game("r"));
 
 paper_div.addEventListener('click', () => game("p"));
 
 scissors_div.addEventListener('click', () => game("s"));
```

Comment: How are you trying to remove the event listeners?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can "disable" the buttons by removing the event listener.

First, you need your event listener function to be a single function like this:

```
function handleRock() {
  game("r");
}
```

Then, you can use addEventListener to add the listener and removeEventListener to remove it like this:

```
rock_div.addEventListener('click', handleRock);

// And when you're ready to disable the rock button:
rock_div.removeEventListener('click', handleRock);
```

NOTE: For removeEventListener to work, its arguments must be **excatly** the same as the arguments to addEventListener. The function must be the **same** function, not just an identical one.

Comment: Thanks, I've edited the code snippet to show how i've been trying to remove the event listeners in the win/lose functions. It doesn't seem to work for some reason. Oh, I see so you're saying I should make the game(r), game(p), game(s) into their own functions. Okay, i'll give that a try!

Comment: In javascript, two function with the same code are not ===. Try this in the console: `(a=>5) === (a=>5)` and you will get false. You are currently creating a new function when you call removeEventListener, but you should save the original function and use it again like I showed in my answer.

Comment: Can you please click to accept my answer?

Comment: oops sorry im a newbie lol i accepted it!